# How to get all lines including dates before today from a textfile in the macOS terminal?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, date-comparison

In a textfile there are lots of dates and I want to `grep` or `find` all the dates before today.

Lines are like `abc def ghi:2018-06-20 mno pqr` and others without a date. The days are chaotic and *not in order*. I want to receive all lines of the file **including a date before today** (not ordered, just as they following in the file).

What I know:

- Today = `date +%Y-%m-%d` and how to save it in a variable `$A`
- Get lines with this date `grep $A file.txt`

I know how to implement this in a for-loop to get maybe some days of a week. But how can I find all the dates before today? I think I do have to get a **comparison** like `if $A > $B do grep $B file.txt`.

Thank you for your help!

*[Yes, I searched a lot but I did not find my solution anywhere.]*

Comment: Is the content of file sorted by date? If not, use `awk`. If sorted use `sed` or `grep`.

Comment: It is not sorted. Just lines, some with dates, some without, and not day by day.

Comment: Do you have another hint for me? Because search for `awk` wasn't leading to my question for me with a solution.

Comment: Post some sample data with expected output.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the  part about "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: Will lines with a date like 02/19/2018 ever occur after a line with the date 2/20/2018

Comment: @JamesBrown Sorry, edited.
@glennjackman Thanks for the hint. I'll try my best everytime.
@jmh Yes, but all in Format `%Y-%m-%d`.

Comment: @TravelTrader, as an aside, `find` is for searching the filesystem. It's useful for finding files but grep, et al., will help you look inside the files once you `find` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ today="$(date "+%s")"
$ input="/tmp/file.txt"
$ cat "${input}"
abc def ghi:2018-06-25 mno pqr
abc def ghi:2018-06-24 mno pqr
abc def ghi:2018-06-23 mno pqr
abc def ghi:2018-06-22 mno pqr
abc def ghi:2018-06-21 mno pqr
abc def ghi:2018-06-20 mno pqr
def ghi:2018-06-20 mno pqr
abc ghi:2018-06-20mno pqr abc
abc def ghi:2017-06-20 mno pqr
abc def2018-06-20 mno pqr
abc def ghi:2018-06-19 mno pqr
def ghi:2018-06-21 mno pqr
abc ghi:2018-07-20 mno pqr
abc def ghi:2018-06-20 mno pqr
abc def2018-05-20 mno pqr
1sss018-05-20 mno pqr
1sss05-20-2018 mno pqr

$ sed -n 's/.*\([[:digit:]]\{4\}-[[:digit:]]\{2\}-[[:digit:]]\{2\}\).*/\1/p' "${input}" \
| sort -u \
| xargs -n1 date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d' '+%s' \
| xargs -n1 -I% awk 'BEGIN{if(%<'${today}'){print %}}' \
| xargs -n1 date -j -f '%s' '+%Y-%m-%d' \
| xargs -n1 -I% grep % $input \
| sort -u
abc def ghi:2017-06-20 mno pqr
abc def ghi:2018-06-19 mno pqr
abc def ghi:2018-06-20 mno pqr
abc def ghi:2018-06-21 mno pqr
abc def ghi:2018-06-22 mno pqr
abc def2018-05-20 mno pqr
abc def2018-06-20 mno pqr
abc ghi:2018-06-20mno pqr abc
def ghi:2018-06-20 mno pqr
def ghi:2018-06-21 mno pqr
```

`$today` is the current date in seconds since the epoch, `$input` is the file you want to parse. `sed` hunts for dates (without verifying they are real dates, for instance 0000-99-99 would match), the first `sort` eliminates duplicate input dates, the first `xargs/date` converts all the found dates into seconds since the epoch, `xargs/awk` outputs all dates to today, the next `xargs/dates` converts the date back to `"%Y-%d-%m"`, `xargs/grep` finds all the preceding dates in the input file, and the last `sort` eliminates any duplicated lines.

Comment: Wow, unbelievable, @keithpjolly ! It works great. I added a grep to it because there were lines I did not need. I especially thank you for your explanations because now I can work on each part of the formula to use it for future challenges. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because there is no option `--color=auto` like for `grep`: Is there a possibility to show the dates (`%Y-%m-%d`) in color?

Comment: @TravelTrader, you can add this after the last sort: ` | egrep --colour=auto '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}'`

Comment: Ha! that 'awk' line was bugging me because I always think awk is used for streams, which is why I had to use the "BEGIN.." line. I figured out a different line that can replace `| xargs ... awk ...`.  It is: `| { for i in $(cat -);do [ "$i" -lt "${today}" ] && echo "$i";done } `  This is the equivalent of the part of your questions where you say "get a comparison like `if $A > $B do ...`"

Comment: I wish stackoverflow made adding code in comments less clunky. :/

Comment: I used your little code everyday. Now I'm changing my system to Ubuntu 18.04. I tried with `date -d` the two date-lines but I don't get a solution for that. Maybe you can help me to transform the `date`-part to linux? Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I got it: `xargs -i date -d '@{}' '+%Y-%m-%d'` and `xargs -i date -d '{}' '+%s'`. I forgot to add the @-sign first. Great code, thanks again for your formula!

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is a very powerful scripting tool that can do the job without resorting to multiple processes and pipes.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    today = systime()
}
/:[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} / {
    for(field=1;field<NF;field++) {
        if (split($field,b,/\:/) > 1)
            gsub(/\-/, " ", b[2])
        if (mktime(b[2] " 0 0 0") > 0)
            if (mktime(b[2] " 0 0 0") < today)
                print $0
        }
}
```

The `BEGIN` block simply sets the variable `today` to the current system time.

`/:[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} /` will only process lines that contain date like strings preceded by a colon `:`

The `for` loop iterates on all the fields in a line to search for this date like string.

The next couple of lines simply split the string into array to get the date string and replacing all dashes `-` with space.

Running `mktime()` on all this date like strings and comparing against today tells us if the line is qualified.

Finally printing the entire line when it qualifies.

Comment: ```
/usr/bin/awk: calling undefined function systime
 source line number 3
```

Comment: @keithpjolley - for `awk`s that don't support `systime()`, one can simply remove the `BEGIN { }` block and pass `-v today=$(date +%s)` as parameter to initialize the `today` variable.

Comment: /usr/bin/awk: calling undefined function mktime

Answer (score 1):

Cool. Now iterate over the dates (for example from today to 6 days ago)  and grep the file for each date:

```
# iterate over i = 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 6
for i in $(seq 0 6); do
     # so substract $i days from today , for eaxmple `date --date="-5 days" +%Y-%m-%d`
     A=$(date --date="-$i days" +%Y-%m-%d)
     grep "$A" file.txt
     # or shorter grep "$(date --date="-$i days" +%Y-%m-%d)" file.txt
done
```

You can also create one big grep argument and this should work faster:

```
grep "$(for i in $(seq 0 6); do echo -n "$(date --date="-$i days" +%Y-%m-%d)\|"; done | sed 's/\\|$//')" file.txt
```

For each date from today to 7 days ago i generate a string that looks ilke `%Y-%m-%d\|`, then i need to remove the last `\|` with `sed 's/\\|$//'`. Then I run grep that looks like `grep "2018-06-23\|2018-06-22\|2018-06-21\|<and so on...>" file.txt`. The `\|` is used as `or` in expressions in grep.

Comment: This workaround I used before. But it was important to show all dates back and not to stop at any point. But your script is more clear and powerful than mine.  Therefore I can work with it, too. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know what column you're looking for the date in, you can also do this:

`awk '$2 < "2020-09-16"' input.txt`

Comment: this came in handy